# Paths.get doesnt find file Windows 10 (java)

Tags: java, file, path, nio

I'm following some course on udemy . Im learning about Paths , but i cant get Paths.get to work.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {


     Path filePath = Paths.get("C:\\OutThere.txt");
     printFile(filePath);

 }

  private static void printFile(Path path){
    try(BufferedReader fileReader = Files.newBufferedReader(path)){
        String line;
        while((line = fileReader.readLine())!=null){
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
 }
 }
```

The File exists , the name is correct and its on the C drive. What am i doing wrong?

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\OutThere.txt

at com.bennydelathouwer.Main.main(Main.java:16)
```

Comment: so, are you saying, you are facing issue only on Windows10 ?

Comment: No idea , i only use windows 10. But the guy who gives the course said there is a diference between mac and windows separators

Comment: There is no `C` drive in Mac, so exact same code won't work anyway in both machine.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad practice to hard-code "/" or "\" use:

```
 File.separator
```

++ are you sure you have the proper privileges to read this file?

Comment: no idea. how do i check for that? i made the file myself so i would gues yes. How should i use File.separator exactly?

Comment: I found the problem . i was stupid. i created a textfile fro testing and i called it OutThere.txt then the program added .txt behind it aswel. so the file name was OutThere.txt.txt

Comment: @BetaBen instead of using "/" or "\" for separation between dirs, use
     File.separator - built in const. used for these purposes